# Find number of days in a given week according to the month for a given date. in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the date "2022-07-02"

For the month July first week only have 3 days in it.

I need to find the number of days in the week for the given date.

In above date the week has 3 days where "2022-07-02" day reside.

Example 2 :

For month June in 2022 first week has 5 days in the week

Therefore if i declare a date  as "2022-06-03" it should pass the number of days in the week as 5

I need a query to find the number of days for the specific week.

Comment: Also, what week doesn't have 7 days in it..? Only ones I can think of is the last week of the year, and the first can with ISO weeks, but those dates don't appear to be the last or first weeks of fiscal years.

Comment: There are always 7 days in a week. This appears to be asking about days in the week in the same month. Please confirm. Also, the answer will depend on the starting day of the week, typically Sunday or Monday. Please clarify this point.

Comment: @GregPavlik yes I need it for a specific month.

Comment: Ex: 2022 May has 6 weeks in the calendar. If I specify the date as '2022-05-01' while only considering the month May, the week where 1st of may reside has only one day which is a sunday.

Answer (score 0):

```
set datefirst 1 -- assumes Monday is set as start of week
declare @myDate date = getdate();
-- calculate the next last day of week
declare @nextSunday date = dateadd(day, 7 - datepart(weekday, @myDate), @myDate);
select case
     -- advancing into the next month implies a partial week
     -- datediff(month, @myDate, nextSunday) = 1 would be equivalent
     when day(@nextSunday) < day(@myDate) then 7 - day(@nextSunday)
     -- else see if still within first week
     when day(@nextSunday) < 7 then day(@nextSunday)
     else 7 end;
```

Within a query you might use it this way:

```
select case
     when day(nextSunday) < day(dateColumn) then 7 - day(nextSunday)
     when day(nextSunday) < 7 then day(nextSunday)
     else 7 end
from
    myData cross apply (
        values (dateadd(day, 7 - datepart(weekday, dateColumn), dateColumn))
    ) v(nextSunday);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee5bfb52dabe31dd619cfd136689db59

If you don't want the shorthand form then just replace every instance of `nextSunday` in the final step with its full expression.

There's nothing in the logic that prevents this from working with another first day of week. I just chose a variable name that helped ellucidate this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task, decided so:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 --first day of the week
DECLARE @MYDATE DATETIME = '2022-07-02'
DECLARE @MYDAYS INT = 0

IF 7 > DATEPART(day,@MYDATE)
BEGIN
SET @MYDAYS = DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(day,7 - DATEPART(weekday,@MYDATE),@MYDATE))
                    - DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(day,-DATEPART(day,@MYDATE) + 1,@MYDATE))
                    + 1
END

IF 7 <= DATEPART(day,@MYDATE)
BEGIN
SET @MYDAYS = 7
END

IF (DATEPART(day,EOMONTH(@MYDATE)) - DATEPART(day,@MYDATE)) < 7
BEGIN
SET @MYDAYS = DATEPART(weekday,EOMONTH(@MYDATE))
END

SELECT @MYDAYS AS 'days in this week of the current month'
```